# How to Use curl for outgoing connection via proxy server

Tags: curl, shoutcast

I have A [shoutcast_Class.php](http://irn-radio.com/shoutcast_class.html) that can retrieve the information from the streaming shoutcast server (example current song;Genry;etc.) I uploaded that on my WEB hosting SERVER and this Script can't retrieve the information from shoutcast server port:5899 Beacuse my WEB SERVER BLOCK this PORT of my SHOUTCAST SERVER, My hosting server allow only port 80 for outgoing connection, I think I need to USE A proxy Server, to allow my script to retrieve the information from my shoutcast server, but how? please help me..

[this the link of The Shoutcast_class.php](http://irn-radio.com/shoutcast_class.html)

Comment: It would be far more reliable if you found another web host that allowed outgoing connections to your port, or if you found a stream host that did streaming on port 80.  In addition, I strongly recommend *not* using that script you have found.  It scrapes the data you want out of the HTML of the admin interface, which is not reliable between varying versions of SHOUTcast.  It would be better to get the data from the XML, or from the stream data itself so that you would not have to be locked in to using SHOUTcast.

Comment: Thanks for that  , Mr. brad, appreciated